# Text is being shifted after jQuery fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I have a jQuery slider I made on a demo site for a client. (Demo: http://awsudbury.fuelmultimedia.ca/)

When the text (really an image) over the orange text gets faded in, it shifts about 20 pixels left and down. Does anybody know why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: Are you checking the width of the image(that is getting left and down shifted) is of lesserwidth than that of the actual element holding it?

Answer (score 1):

Split your .home_slider li.current .featured_wrap rule (line 271) into two rules:

```
.home_slider li .featured_wrap {
    background: url("img/image_text_area_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: -17px;
    height: 314px;
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 627px;
}

.home_slider li.current .featured_wrap{
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but didn't fix the problem at all.

Comment: Well it fixed it on firebug :)

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if this is the best way to have fixed this, but I just targeted the absolute positioning of both the .current elements and the non-current.

```
.home_slider li.current .featured_text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 300;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 80px;
}

.home_slider li .featured_text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 300;
    bottom: 18px;
    left: 70px;
}
```